# XPath Query to return nodes of a certain ComplexType

Tags: xml, xpath, complextype

Lets say I have a ComplexType called CarType that is applied to elements such as Sedan and SUV. How do I write an XPath query that returns all of the Sedan and SUV nodes by just using CarType?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a schema-aware XPath 2.0 processor,

```
//element(*, CarType)
```

Comment: I built the schema using XML Spy but the generated XML gets stored in a SQL Server table and I have to pull the values via a T-SQL Query.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what subset of XQuery/XPath the current SQL Server products support.